# My angular can't get the value from html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an angular function to call me rest service but it can't get the value from the html file. when i press submit the $scope.productForm is, although i still have value in my html page.

Main.js

```
$scope.products = [];
$scope.productForm = {
    ID:1,
    Name:"",
    Description:"",
    URL:""
};

_refreshProductData();

//Add or Update Product
$scope.submitProduct = function() {  
    var method = "";
     
    if ($scope.productForm.ID == -1) {
        method = "POST";
    } else {
        method = "PUT";
    }
     
    $http({ 
        method: method,
        url: '/product',
        data: angular.toJson($scope.productForm),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(_success, _error);
 }
```

index.html

```html
<form ng-submit="submitProduct()">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>ProductID</td>
            <td>{{productForm.ID}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="productForm.Name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Description</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="productForm.Description"  /></td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>Product URL</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="productForm.URL"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="blue-button" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

data: angular.toJson($scope.productForm) can have value from index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope._refreshProductData();-->  you should call your function this way.
_refreshProductData();-->_refreshProductData is not defined(F12)
```

I have assumed that the function was created in my previous answer.

```
1)create your function in main.js
   $scope._refreshProductData() = function()
   {
     write codes here...  
   }
```

then call the function in place

```
2) $scope._refreshProductData();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an [explanation of how and why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: when i change form,  _refreshProductData(); -> $scope._refreshProductData();
the errror is : $scope._refreshProductData is not a function

Comment: can you share the entire code.Are you sure you have a function named _refreshProductData in main.js.create your function in main.js($scope._refreshProductData = function(){ write codes here }), then call the function in place ($scope._refreshProductData())

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you have a number of things you need to address.

1. `main.js` doesn't have a function `_refreshProductData` defined. I'm assuming this is breaking your script and why `$scope.submitProduct()` isn't executing.
2. When defining your `_refreshProductData` function, you need to attach it to the controller's `$scope`(i.e. `$scope._refreshProductData = function(){//refresh data}` if you want it to be accessible to the html template. Otherwise, you wouldn't need to attach `$scope` to it. You would need to update your call to this function based on the approach you take.